# LAMBDA error: conditional expression of type 'void' is illegal

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to review this C++ premier plus book, however while checking LAMBDA part I get into a compile error on my VBS 2013

```
    // use captured variables
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
const long Size = 390000L;


int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    std::vector<int> numbers(Size);
std::srand(std::time(0));
std::generate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), std::rand);
cout << "Sample size = " << Size << '\n';

// using lambdas
/*int count3 = std::count_if(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(),
    [](int x){return x % 3 == 0; });
cout << "Count of number divisible by 3: " << count3 << '\n';*/

int count13 = 0;
std::count_if(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(),
    [&count13](int x){count13 += x % 13 == 0; });
cout << "count of number divisible by 13: " << count13 << '\n';

// using a single lambda
/*int count3 = 0;
int count13 = 0;
std::for_each(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(),
    [&](int x){count3 += x % 3 == 0; count13 += x % 13 == 0; });
cout << "Count of number divisible by 3: " << count3 << '\n';
cout << "Count of number divisible by 13: " << count13 << '\n';


  */
    return 0;

}
```

The uncommented part is the one I get: conditional expression of type 'void' is illegal. I think the compiler is trying to read the lambda expression closurert{body} as conditional operator Exp1 ? Exp2 : Exp3;.

Also the idea of this exercise is that while using 2+ lambdas or 1 joint lambda it should return the same value output, which in my case it doesn't.

Appreciate your enlightenment...

Comment: You forgot a return statement in the lambda. And you might want to include some parentheses for clarity.

Comment: if you're using `count_if` you should input condition for counted elements as a third argument, if you want to count them in captured variable perhaps you need `for_each`.

Comment: thanks Borgleader, just didn't notice...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you did not use a return statement in a lambda expression and did not used a trailing return type then the return type of the lambda evaluation is considered as `void`.

Instead of

```
int count13 = 0;
std::count_if(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(),
    [&count13](int x){count13 += x % 13 == 0; });
```

you should write

```
int count13 = std::count_if( numbers.begin(), numbers.end(),
                             [](int x ) { return x % 13 == 0; } );
```

In this case the return type of the lambda is deduced as `bool`.

Or if you want to use a variable captured by reference that to count numbers that are divisible by 13 then it is better to use standard algorithm `std::for_each` For example

```
int count13 = 0;
std::for_each( numbers.begin(), numbers.end(),
               [&count13]( int x ) { count13 += x % 13 == 0; } );
```

In this case it is equivalent to the range based for statement

```
int count13 = 0;
for ( int x : numbers ) count13 += x % 13 == 0;
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad, I miss the return type. But then why is working below without return type? `code`[&](int x){count3 += x % 3 == 0; count13 += x % 13 == 0; });`code` and is giving me different output while using 2 lambdas or 1 combine? Sample size = 390000
Count of number divisible by 3: 130086
count of number divisible by 13: 29792

Sample size = 390000
Count of number divisible by 3: 129858
Count of number divisible by 13: 29801

Comment: @maurux If you mean the std::for_each algorithm then its lambda expression has return type void because the return type of the lambda is not used in the algorithm. You are incrementing captured variable count13 within the lambda expression.

Comment: @maurux You have chenged your original comment such a way that I do not understand what you want to ask.:)

Comment: yes, sorry about that. but I did understand you. My last point/question is: The idea of this exercise is that while using 2 separate lambdas for count3, count13 or 1 joint lambda for count3 and count13, should return the same value output for count3= 130086 and count13 = 29792 , which in my case it doesn't. Using 2 lambdas gives me a different output than using 1 lambda

Comment: @maurux The result shall be the same whether you are using two count_if algorithms or one std::for_each for two counters.

Comment: @ Vlad from Moscow Thanks men! kudos for you :)